# Why is the refresh to pull icon stuck refreshing?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this RefreshCommand which I use to refresh a database of "notes", but when I refresh the page, instead of refreshing for 2 seconds and then just giving me the notes, it keeps on refreshing, which isn't what I would like it to do, plus it lags the app.

Here is the code

MyNotePage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
     xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:MvvmHelpers;assembly=MvvmHelpers"
     xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
     xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
     x:Class="MyApp.MyNotePage"
     x:DataType="viewmodels:MyNoteViewModel"
     BackgroundColor="White">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:MyNoteViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ListView
BackgroundColor="Transparent"
CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
HasUnevenRows="True"
IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Note}"
RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
RefreshControlColor="DarkViolet"
SelectionMode="None"
SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Note">
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem
                    Command="{Binding Source={Binding MyNotePage}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    IsDestructive="True"
                    Text="Delete"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label
                                FontSize="Large"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label
                                FontSize="Small"
                                Text="{Binding Id}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MyNotePage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyApp
{

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyNotePage
    {
        public MyNotePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

MyNoteViewModel.cs

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MyNoteViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public ObservableRangeCollection<Note> Note { get; }
        public AsyncCommand RefreshCommand { get; }

        public AsyncCommand AddCommand { get; }

        public AsyncCommand<Note> RemoveCommand { get; }
        public new bool IsBusy { get; private set; }

        public MyNoteViewModel()
        {

            Note = new ObservableRangeCollection<Note>();

            RefreshCommand = new AsyncCommand(Refresh);
            AddCommand = new AsyncCommand(Add);
            RemoveCommand = new AsyncCommand<Note>(Remove);
        }

        async Task Add()
        {
            var name = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Notes", "Enter your notes here");
            await NoteService.AddNote(name);
            await Refresh();
        }

        async Task Remove(Note note)
        {
            await NoteService.RemoveNote(note.Id);
            await Refresh();
        }


        async Task Refresh()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Note.Clear();
            var notes = await NoteService.GetNote();
            Note.AddRange(notes);
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And NoteService.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public static class NoteService
    {

        static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
        static async Task Init()
        {

            if (db != null)
                return;
            {
                var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");

                db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

                await db.CreateTableAsync<Note>();
            }
        }

        public static async Task AddNote(string name)
        {
            await Init();
            var note = new Note()
            {
                Name = name,
            };

            await db.InsertAsync(note);

        }
        public static async Task RemoveNote(int id)
        {
            await Init();
            await db.DeleteAsync<Note>(id);

        }
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Note>> GetNote()
        {
            await Init();

            var note = await db.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
            return note;

        }

    }
}
```

Maybe it is something to do with IsBusy? I don't know if I set that up properly. The bool does change from false to true but it looks like it doesn't do the opposite to stop the refresh. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pointed this out to you in your previous question.  IsBusy does not raise a PropertyChanged event so the UI is never notified